#  Add items dynamically to ResourceDictionary. Convert File path to resource Key

Tags: wpf, silverlight, file, path

I have ResourceDictionary in my application. I need to add some items from c# code to this collection:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

As key for resources i want to use path to file. 
For example:

c:\some folder\@#file.txt

What is the best wey to convert this file path to valid ResourceDictionary Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <sys:String x:Key="c&#x3A;some&#x20;folder&#x23;file.txt">
            whatever
        </sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>    
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{StaticResource c&#x3A;some&#x20;folder&#x23;file.txt}" />
</Grid>
```

Remove back slash and encode special characters.

Comment: nope. I mean that i need to have key like that: <sys:String x:Key="c__some_folder_file_txt">Value</sys:String>. I dont know what symbols i need to remove and how.

Comment: If i will just add this key like new Resource(){Key=path}. WPF will encode symbols automatically or i need to do it in code?

Comment: @Evgeny Encoding is for Xaml. In code behind you don't have to do it. Just remove back slashes.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfskins.aspx) on CP tell you how use loose XAML files at Runtime, also some other. Have a look.